# Hibernate Tools : how to generate base classes?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-tools

I recently installed Eclipse Helios and Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1.

I've been trying to generate "base class" from mapping files but can't find out how to do.
Let us say I have a mapping file called Individual.hbm.xml.
I want Hibernate Tools to generate 2 POJOs : 
- a BaseIndividual.java that would contain constructors and getters/setters
- an Individual.java where I could add "custom" code that would not be removed whenever I re-generate POJOs

I spent a lot of time seeking information but never found a practical answer.
If anyone can help... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have just come across your question while trying to do the same thing myself (I think).

What I have done is set the following in my hbm.xml config file:

```
<class
    name="User"
    table="USERS">
    <meta attribute="generated-class">ocs.authentication.UserBase</meta>
    <id
        name="user_id"
        column="USER_ID"
        type="integer">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property
        name="username"
        column="USERNAME"
        type="string" />
</class>
```

Note the `<meta attribute="generated-class">` section. This will cause the generated class to be called UserBase (in this case).
You can then create another class (called User for example) that will extend this base class:

```
public class User extends UserBase {

    public User() {
    }

    public void SomeFunction() {
    ...
    }

}
```

This seems to be working for me.
I hope this is useful for you, or for others wanting to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a way to do it as well.
What I'm doing right now, is to:

- to save my custom class "Individual.java" to another package without updating the reference.
- generate all my pojo (with the name of the table, ie Individual)
- rename them tablename+"Base" (ie IndividualBase) without updating the references)
- then moving my custom class (Individual) which extends the pojo from the other package.

Did you find out an automatic way to do it by for example:

- Using a custom template
- Writing you own ant task
- Configure hibernate.reveng.xml

I agree that Hibernate Synchronizer was doing it quite well!